# Sphinx import module error - method not defined

Tags: python, mocking, python-sphinx, nameerror

I want to make a sphinx documentation project with my python scripts, which have a custom library, let's call it myLibrary, several functions, e.g. funct1.
The problem is that when I try to make the html files for my functions, in one script I receive the  warning:

**NameError: name 'funct1' is not defined.**

I tried following the guidelines using mock() as in this page (http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-make-your-sphinx-documentation-compile-with-readthedocs-when-youre-using-numpy-and-scipy/) or by adding in the conf.py file:

```
autodoc_mock_imports=['myLibrary']
```

however the problem persists. Perhaps  it has to do with the fact that the script begins with:

```
from myLibrary import *
```

Is there a way to workaround this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: I wont be able to help but it will be helpful for others to see the whole code or an example

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the problem by adding a fictitious library with the funct1 to the site-packages folder of python37.